# Remote query of multiple servers using Get-EventLog in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script for my morning routine. I want to pull only the Warnings and Errors from a list of remote servers. Currently I am only getting either Warnings or Errors. I am not certain how to retrieve both. Once I pull the info, it doesn't include the server. My query is below:

```
# SERVER LIST PROPERTIES
# Get computer list to check disk space. This is just a plain text file with the servers listed out.
 $computers = Get-Content "C:\MorningChecks.txt"; 

# QUERY COMPUTER SYSTEM EVENT LOG
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
 Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-1) | Format-Table -Wrap ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-EntryType` Parameter accepts an array of strings for the filtering.

So to filter only for Errors you would use the parameter:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)
```

To filter for Errors and Warnings:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType "Error","Warning" -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)
```

To get the computer name, you have to add it to the `-Property` parameter on the end of the `Format-Table`:

```
Format-Table -Wrap -Property MachineName, Index, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, InstanceID, Message -AutoSize
```

-- Edit

To answer your question on the machine name showing your own machine, it's because when you run `Get-EventLog` you are just running it for your local machine. You forgot to specify the `-ComputerName` parameter in your `foreach` loop. Your foreach loop should look like:

```
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
 Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System -EntryType "Error","Warning" -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-1) | Format-Table -Wrap -Property MachineName, Index, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, InstanceID, Message -AutoSize ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still having an issue. MachineName returns my local hostname. Not the remote hostname.