# Powershell Get_EventLog for multiple servers

Tags: windows, powershell, get-eventlog

I'm a SQL DBA, n00b to Powershell, tasked with sysadmin duties at the moment

I need to query error logs across my servers for Errors and Warnings.

Using my own Google-fu and help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262757/remote-query-of-multiple-servers-using-get-eventlog-in-powershell) thread I was able to get this working:

```
 $computers = Get-Content "C:\Servers\ServerList_Short.txt"; 

# QUERY COMPUTER SYSTEM EVENT LOG
foreach($computer in $computers)

{        
     Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System -EntryType "Error","Warning" -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-7) `
     | Select-Object -Property machineName, EntryType, EventID, TimeGenerated, Message `
     | Format-Table -Property MachineName, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source,  Message -AutoSize ;

}
```

What I am missing at the moment is how to trap for a server in my .txt file that is offline, ignore it and move to the next one.   After that, I will be working to dump all of this to a SQL table, results.txt, etc.

Thanks for any help :)]

Kevin3NF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to handle this but I'd recommend combining a `Test-Connection` with a `Try/Catch`, the `Test-Connection` will make it so that you only try to query the servers which respond to ping and then the `Try/Catch` will handle any other errors that may come along.

```
foreach($computer in $computers)

{        
 if(Test-Connection $computer -Quiet -Count 1){
    Try {
        Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System -EntryType "Error","Warning" -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-7) `
     | Select-Object -Property machineName, EntryType, EventID, TimeGenerated, Message `
     | Format-Table -Property MachineName, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source,  Message -AutoSize
    } Catch {
        Write-Verbose "Error $($error[0]) encountered when attempting to get events from  $computer"
    }
 } else {
    Write-Verbose "Failed to connect to $computer"
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks!  I have a 3 server list for testing, one doesn't exist.   Got this back after the good results:   Test-Connection : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the 
command again.

Comment: The error means you have a blank line at the end of your file, you can overcome it by chaning the nesting nad putting the `test-connection` inside of the `try/catch` or just make sure your file doesn't have blank lines at the end, either on the front-end or by doing a `$computers = $computers | Where-object {$_}` which will elminate null values from your array

Comment: Perfect...must have had a CR;LF...removed that, ran against my full server list and it worked...thanks!!!